# need to speed up C# application that converts timestamps

Tags: c#

im having a tough time getting a small application to work faster. im not a developer and it took me some time to get this working as is. Can anyone offer any suggestions or alternate code to speed this process up, its taking about 1 Hour to process 10m of the input file.

the code is listed below and here is an example of the input file.

> 4401,imei:0000000000,2012-09-01 12:12:12.9999

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
if (args.Length == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }


                using (FileStream stream = File.Open(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {

                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                            var values = line.Split(',');
                            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                            DateTime.TryParse(values[2], out dt);
                            values[2] = Convert.ToString(dt.Ticks);

                            string[] output = new string[values.Length];
                            bool firstColumn = true;
                            for (int index = 0; index < values.Length; index++)
                            {
                                if (!firstColumn)
                                    builder.Append(',');
                                builder.Append(values[index]);
                                firstColumn = false;

                            }
                            File.WriteAllText(args[1], builder.AppendLine().ToString());

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The biggest performance hit is that every time a line is read the entire file (processed so far) is written back to disk. For a quick win, try moving your StringBuilder out of the loop:

```
            System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            using (FileStream stream = File.Open(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                        var values = line.Split(',');
                        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                        DateTime.TryParse(values[2], out dt);
                        values[2] = Convert.ToString(dt.Ticks);

                        string[] output = new string[values.Length];
                        bool firstColumn = true;
                        for (int index = 0; index < values.Length; index++)
                        {
                            if (!firstColumn)
                                builder.Append(',');
                            builder.Append(values[index]);
                            firstColumn = false;
                        }
                        builder.AppendLine();
                    }
                }
            }

            File.WriteAllText(args[1], builder.ToString());
```

If you want to refactor further change the comma separating logic:

```
            System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            using (FileStream stream = File.Open(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                        var values = line.Split(',');
                        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                        DateTime.TryParse(values[2], out dt);
                        values[2] = Convert.ToString(dt.Ticks);

                        builder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", values));
                    }
                }
            }

            File.WriteAllText(args[1], builder.ToString());
```

**Edit:** To avoid the memory usage, remove the `Stringbuilder` and use another `FileStream` to write to disk. Your proposed solution (using a `List`) will still use a substantial amount of memory and likely break on larger files:

```
        using (FileStream input = File.Open(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (FileStream output = File.Create(args[1]))
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(input))
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(output))
            {
                while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',');
                    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                    DateTime.TryParse(values[2], out dt);
                    values[2] = Convert.ToString(dt.Ticks);

                    streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(",", values));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Might also want to go directly for `values[2] = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Parse(values[2]).Ticks)` if the format is expected to be always right.

Comment: @Muzz your second refactoring worked great for the 130m file i have. however using it against a 440m file, it threw a memory exception "Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException.".

any suggestions to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

here is what i found can fix this and handle the large files.

thanks to @Muzz and @Vache for the assistance.

```
string line = ""; 
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:/test.txt"); 
List<string> convertedLines = new List<string>(); 
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) 
{
    string[] lineSplit = line.Split(','); 
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(); 
    DateTime.TryParse(lineSplit[2], out dt); 
    lineSplit[2] = Convert.ToString(dt.Ticks); 
　
    string convertedline = lineSplit[0] + "," + lineSplit[1] + "," + lineSplit[2]; 
    convertedLines.Add(convertedline);
}
file.Close();
File.WriteAllLines("c:/newTest.txt", convertedLines);
```